# Problem with prisma relations after upgrading to 4.11 and referentialIntegrity

Tags: mysql, prisma

So I had the following models(changed names to make it more simple to understand I guess)

```
model User {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  name  String @db.VarChar(256)
  jobs  Job[]
  tasks Task[]

  @@unique([userId, name])
  @@index([userId])
}

model Job {
  id            String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId        String
  user          User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: NoAction)
  currentTaskId String?
  currentTask   Task?   @relation(fields: [currentTaskId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, name: "currentTask")
  tasks         Task[]  @relation(name: "tasks")

  @@index([userId])
}

model Task {
  id          String @id @default(cuid())
  siteId      String
  site        User   @relation(fields: [siteId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: NoAction)
  jobId       String
  job         Job    @relation(fields: [jobId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, name: "tasks")
  currentJobs Job[]  @relation(name: "currentTask")

  @@index([userId])
  @@index([jobId])
}
```

Where:
1 user could have many jobs
1 Job could have many tasks, but each job only has one current Task.

this used to work fine with referentialIntegrity, but now when I try to delete an user I get the following error:

```
The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'tasks' between the `Task ` and `Job ` models.
  meta: {
    relation_name: 'tasks',
    model_a_name: 'Task',
    model_b_name: 'Job '
  }
```

I think this is because some cyclic problem when using relationMode = "prisma", where it tries to delete the Jobs, but those have tasks, and those tasks have jobs.

I tried multiple ways (even asked chatGPT for help, it was clueless too.) but always ended up getting the same error or "Reference causes a cycle" when trying to set onDelete to cascade on both Job and Tasks models...

Hope someone have an idea whats wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In task you don't need/shouldn't have `job         Job` and `currentJobs Job[]`

Comment: You also don't need a relation to task in job `currentTask   Task?` just add a flag on Task that it is running true/false... everything else is just querying.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think those answers really help in my problem because I use the information fetched by prisma in those relations, for example: fetching the users from a current tasks from a job or any other specific thing without rawquerying.

include: {
        currentTask: {
          include: {
            user: true,
          }
        }
      }

Thanks anyway

Comment: Well the (documentation)[https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations] about relation backs up my assertion the `relation` is not supposed to exist in the database if it does, the model is wrong.